# Upgrading legacy signing key to a new signing key

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, android-keystore, android-app-signing

After a new update in my app i got a warning on google play console asking me to upgrade the apps signature to a stronger one.
OK, but now i can't update my app with my old keystore.jks

***Your Android App Bundle was signed with an incorrect key. Use the correct signing key and try again. It should be signed with a certificate with the following fingerprint***

what should i do to fix this? I have the old keystore.jks and the privatekey.
Can i create a new keystore with the new certificates?

I tried to import the new certificate in the keystore but no success.

Thanks in advance